# Automate AWS SSO login using selenium

Tags: selenium, amazon-s3

Can anyone tell me how is AWS SSO login automation done using Selenium? I am trying to login to AWS account with Selenium but I am not aware how to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. I just typed in the link and the SSO token for login. Just worked simply by driver.get command.